# Sublime text 2: Is it possible to get autocomplete for Stylus?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext2, stylus

I just started using Stylus and it seems very nice. I even found a syntax highlighter extension that seems to work nicely.

Does anyone know if it's possible to get autocomplete working with it?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [plugin](https://github.com/billymoon/Stylus)

And not to seem rude, but I only had to [google](https://www.google.se/search?q=sublime%20text%202%20stylus&aq=f&oq=sublime%20text&aqs=chrome.0.59j0j57j60l2j0.2618&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) `sublime text 2 stylus` to get this answer, it was even the first result. So try researching a bit more before you ask questions the next time. ;)

Comment: Thank you Daniel! 
I actually googled the same thing and used that exact same plugin you recommended. But apparently the autocomplete did not start working until closing and re-opening tabs, so it first seemed like syntax highlighting was working but autocomplete not so I thought that I'd need separate solution for that.