# Sublime Text Stylus Autocompletion?

Tags: sublimetext3, stylus

I have both the Stylus plugin and the Stylus-Snippets plugin installed..do these not come with an autocomplete feature? If so, does it need to be turned on somewhere? The view syntax is set on Stylus.

If I set the syntax back to CSS the autocomplete for properties turns back on, but then I obviously lose all the Stylus syntax highlighting etc..

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591893/sublime-text-2-is-it-possible-to-get-autocomplete-for-stylus

Apparently that guy got it working by closing and reopening the tabs. Give it a shot.

Comment: It looks like as im manually using properties, the autocompleter is learning them. Eg, typing `color` the first time did not trigger an autocomplete, but using it a second time I saw that the autocomplete was now available. Both cool thats its learning but strange that it isnt autocompleting out of the box.

Comment: Ok, this is quite annoying. It seems that what its "learned" gets reset when using a new file. Seriously how can this be fixed? Has anyone else ran into this issue?